# Sublime Text regex working only if not escaped

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext, regex-lookarounds

In sublime text 3, why does this match 3 entries

```
\$http\.post\('\/((?!view|list).)[^\']*'
```

but this matches nothing

```
\$http\.post\('\/((?!view|list).)[^\']*\'
```

on the following dataset.

```
$http.post('/listSets' ,$scope.updateAccessKey({type: 2}), {
$http.post('/viewedMessage' , viewedMessagePayload, {
$http.post('/listRelatedContent' , 
$http.post('/viewedSet' , payLoad , {
$http.post('/viewDiscussion' , payLoad , {
$http.post('/editMessage' , $scope.updateAccessKey(payLoad), {
$http.post('/addComment' , $scope.updateAccessKey(payLoad), {
$http.post('/createStudySet' , createSetP
```

I know that escaping the apostrophe is optional but why does it break Sublime Text regex search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation on Search and Replace](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions), internally Sublime uses the Boost PCRE engine to power regular expressions in search panels, and according to the [Boost Regex documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), the construct `\'` is synonymous with `\z` and matches only at the end of a buffer.

So the version of your regex that ends in `\'` doesn't match anything because by definition it only matches something that looks like a `$http.post` line which appears in the last line of the file and which ends the file with the URL string still unterminated.

Due to the `*` prior to `\'` in the regex, it will match any amount of text that follows such a line, so long as it doesn't contain a single quote (due to the exclusion in the character class).

For example, given the following input, your regex will match the last `$http.post`, including everything following it right up to the end of the buffer.

```
$http.post('/listSets' ,$scope.updateAccessKey({type: 2}), {
$http.post('/viewedMessage' , viewedMessagePayload, {
$http.post('/listRelatedContent' , 
$http.post('/viewedSet' , payLoad , {
$http.post('/viewDiscussion' , payLoad , {
$http.post('/editMessage' , $scope.updateAccessKey(payLoad), {
$http.post('/addComment' , $scope.updateAccessKey(payLoad), {
$http.post('/createStudySet , $scope.updateAccessKey(payLoad), {

And then some other non code stuff here.
Basically anything but a single quote.
```

Comment: SublimeText2 uses Boost. SublimeText3 uses full-fledged PCRE regex engine. Run a `overgrow(*SKIP)(*F)|grow` regex over `grow growl overgrown` and you will see it works (Boost does not support the PCRE verbs).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew looking at the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.backtracking_control_verbs), (as linked in the answer,) `SKIP` and `FAIL` are supported by Boost, though indeed Boost doesn't support all control verbs like `MARK`. Indeed, `MARK` (using the example from http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#mark) doesn't work in ST3, so it really does seem like it uses Boost - do you have any other evidence to support the notion that ST3 doesn't use Boost?

Comment: SublimeText2 does not support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Notepad++ that is using Boost does not support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. The point is that SublimeText3 uses PCRE now. You may find differences even if you just test `]` (or `}`) - in SublimeText2, that char must be escaped outside a character class, in SublimeText3, it is not necessary (as is correct in PCRE).